# PSQL Query to get duplicate records of same value in different columns in one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table (customers) has 5 columns (name, mobile, mobile2, mobile3, mobile4),
there is same mobile value in different columns of mobile

Example

```
if value of mobile in (mobile2, mobile3, mobile4)
or
if value of mobile2 in (mobile, mobile3, mobile4)
or
if value of mobile3 in (mobile, mobile2, mobile4)
or
if value of mobile4 in (mobile, mobile2, mobile3)
```

Example

| id | name | mobile | mobile2 | mobile3 | mobile4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | customer | 01277889910 |  |  |  |
| 2 | customer1 |  |  | 01277889910 |  |
| 3 | customer2 |  | 01277889910 |  |  |
| 4 | customer3 |  |  | 028877456 |  |
| 5 | customer4 |  |  |  | 028877456 |

I need the result of the query each two or more records grouped together
example
[(1,2,3), (4,5)]

as id 1, 2 and 3 are have the same mobile number in (mobile column, mobile3 column and mobile2 column)
also id 3 and 4 are have the same mobile number in (mobile3 column and mobile4 column)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would it be possible to normalize this table instead? A table for mobile numbers with reference to the customer table would be appropriate ;)

Comment: You can group your example data by `coalesce( mobile, mobile2, mobile3, mobile4)`

Answer (score 0):

If only one of the `mobileX` columns has a non-null value per record (see the comment by @Serg) then

```sql
select array_agg(id_list) from
(
 select coalesce(mobile, mobile2, mobile3, mobile4) as mobile_no,
        string_agg(id::text, ',') as id_list, 
 from the_table 
 group by mobile_no
) t;
```

Still it is worth thinking about normalizing the table as @JimJones noticed. You may use `json_agg` instead of `string_agg` and `array_agg` too.